# Wilcard search or partial matching in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I am trying to provide the search to end user with type as they go which is is more like sqlserver.
I was able to implement ES query for the given  sql scenario:

```sql
select * from table where name like '%pete%' and type != 'xyz and type!='abc'
```

But the ES query doesnt work for this sql query

```sql
select * from table where name like '%peter tom%' and type != 'xyz and type!='abc'
```

In my elastic search alongwith the wildcard query i also need to perform some boolean filtered query

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query": {
                "wildcard": {
                  "name": { "value": "*pete*" }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": { "type": "xyz" }
            },
            {
              "match": { "type": "abc" }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above elastic query with wildcard search works fine and gets me all the documents that matches pete and are not of type xyz and abc .But when i try perform the wildcard with 2 seprate words seprated by space then the same query returns me empty as shown below.For example

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query": {
                "wildcard": {
                  "name": { "value": "*peter tom*" }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": { "type": "xyz" }
            },
            {
              "match": { "type": "abc" }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My mapping is as follows :

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

What query should i use in order to make wild card search possible for  words seprated by spaces

Comment: You problem is that you dont understand how ES indexing data. Look to this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html. Also look to ngGram https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Comment: So problem is that when you index text "hello world" in ES it will become ["hello", "world"].

Comment: i understand how documents are stored in ES but what does ES provide to allow users to perform sql like search for words seprated by spaces is my question

Comment: Do you need like or or you need to find similar? so for instance if user search for "piter tom" is that ok if you show also "peter tom"?

Comment: i would like a LIKE operation on both side . i.e like '%peter to%' as we do in sql

Comment: which version of ES you are using?

Comment: i am using 2.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient solution involves leveraging an [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) in order to tokenize portions of your `name` field. For instance, if you have a name like `peter tomson`, the ngram tokenizer will tokenize and index it like this:

- pe
- pet
- pete
- peter
- peter t
- peter to
- peter tom
- peter toms
- peter tomso
- eter tomson
- ter tomson
- er tomson
- r tomson
- tomson
- tomson
- omson
- mson
- son
- on

So, when this has been indexed, searching for any of those tokens will retrieve your document with `peter thomson` in it.

Let's create the index:

```
PUT likequery
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "15"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "typename": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "search": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll then be able to search like this with a simple and very efficient `term` query:

```
POST likequery/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.search": "peter tom"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "xyz"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback ,would you let know the specfic of these 2 attributes : "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "15" .is 2 representing the bigram , in that case what does max_gram signifies . Also is ngram available in 2.1 version ?

Comment: `min_gram` is minimum number of characters (not words) and `max_gram` is the maximum number of characters, this means that this tokenizer will tokenize and index all character strings of length 2 to 15 that can be made from your name values.

Comment: @Val i have question what if you have document "peter anderson" for instance. it will still match it?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat no it won't unless we throw some fuzziness into the mix

Comment: @Val perfect because i thought that search term will go via same tokenizer but its not. That is why i was waiting for your solutioN :)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat You can also have the search term go through the same tokenizer if needed

Comment: if i have name field like "peter thomsan robert islovakia" ,Will the ngram filter with min_gram of 2 and max_gram of 15 create all possible for each of the 4 tokens in this sentence  or it will create all possiblity from 2 nd character to 15th character

Comment: @andy of course 15 was just a sample, if you expect larger strings, you need to increase 15 to something bigger

Comment: Is ngram search query case sensitive.If i type in Peter tomson it doesnt work while peter tomson works fine.How can make the ngram filter case insensitive

Comment: You need to add a `lowercase` token filter to the `my_ngram_analyzer`. Simply add `"filter": ["lowercase"]` after your tokenizer

Comment: thanks , and if i have something like Babson CLO Ltd. 2014 in the document does it mean the user need to type "Babson CLO Ltd." to get to this document .If i type in"Babson CLO Ltd 2014" it does not return anything .Is punctuation and full stop not ignored in ngram analyzer like other ES query

Comment: No, the ngram analyzer takes everything by default, but you can [configure it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to fit your needs using the `token_chars` setting.

Comment: i extended my query on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161762/ngram-for-wildcard-search-in-elastic-search since the discussion was getting long.

Answer (score 1):

Well my solution is not perfect and I am not sure about performance. So you should try it on your own risk :)

This is es 5 version

```
PUT likequery
{
  "mappings": {
    "typename": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in ES 2.1 change **"type": "keyword"** to **"type": "string", "index":    "not_analyzed"**

```
PUT likequery/typename/1
{
  "name": "peter tomson"
}

PUT likequery/typename/2
{
  "name": "igor tkachenko"
}

PUT likequery/typename/3
{
  "name": "taras shevchenko"
}
```

Query is **case sensetive**

```
POST likequery/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "name.raw": ".*taras shev.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "likequery",
        "_type": "typename",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "raw": [
            "taras shevchenko"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

PS. Once again I am not sure about performance of this query since it will use scan and not index.