# ngram for wildcard search in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to provide the search to end user with type as they go which is is more like sqlserver. I was able to implement ES query for the given sql scenario:

```
 select * from table where name like '%peter tom%' and type != 'xyz
```

In ES i used ngram tokenizer in order to achieve the desired results :

```
PUT sample
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "15"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "typename": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "search": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.search": "peter tom"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "xyz"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So if my document rows are like

```
name                              type
peter tomson                      efg
Peter tomson robert simson        efg
```

The above query only shows be both the documents but when i try to type in Peter sims or Peter simson it doesnt return the second document unless i type in Peter tomson robert sims or Peter tomson robert simson .So basically i have to type all the following words after Peter and before simson to get to the second document . Is there any way to get the second document with partial matching .I can use the query match with and "AND" operation but that is still on exact match of the word.I am looking for partial match like Peter sims should give me second row of the documents .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the query myself posting the solution for further reference for other users :

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete"
                    ]
                },
                "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 40
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "title": "peter tomson" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/2
{
  "title": "Peter tomson robert simson" 
}


GET my_index/doc/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "title": {
            "query": "Pete sim", 
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Helps beginners like me!

Comment: I think it fails in some cases. Try to insert 2 more docs("SP SSPT" , "PSS SSPT2") and search for "sp sspt", it gives both the result.