# Convert SQL to ElasticSearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this sql

```
Select * from a where a.col1 like %search_str% OR a.col2 like %search_str%  OR a.col3 like %search_str%;
```

What will be Elastic Search Query for this?

Used this :

```
var query = {
      "query" => {
          "multi_match" => {
                  "query" => "#{search_str}",
                  "fields" =>["col1","col2","col3"]
          }
      }
  }
```

Not Getting very accurate results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093662/wilcard-search-or-partial-matching-in-elastic-search/41094077#41094077

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
{
"bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query":      "#{search_str}",
            "type":       "cross_fields",
            "fields":     [ "col1", "col2", "col3" ],
            "fuzziness": 2,
            "minimum_should_match": "50%" 
          }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: And how like suppose to work if he index value "hello world" and search term is "llo"

Comment: You need to include an additional "fuzzy_query" (edit distance 2) in the above bool query, if you want to catch 'llo' as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the research to an equal or like operation, you don't need to analyze the text.

Change the mapping to a keyword to avoid the analysis and then use a wildcard or regex to search in the single entire chunk of text.

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) for details.

```
PUT _template/test
{
  "template":   "test-*",
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": { 
        "enabled": false
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings_as_keywords": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here an example to create a template for all new indexes starting with name *test-*, that:

- map all the strings as simple keywords without a character limit
- normalize data in input for case insensitive, accent insensitive researches
- remove the _all field

And probably you want to convert the query to a filter to match exactly your items and don't use a score system

```
GET /test-1/movies/_search
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "title": "*tar war*"
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "title": "*ord of the ring*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```