# Query in ElasticSearch to match part of the word

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query in ElasticSearch which matches contiguous characters in the words. So, if my index has "John Doe", I should still see "John Doe" returned by Elasticsearch for the below searches.

1. john doe
2. john do
3. ohn do
4. john
5. n doe

I have tried the below query so far.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "term",
      "operator": "OR",
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "fields": [
        "Field1",
        "Field2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this also returns unnessary matches like I will still get "John Doe" when i type john x.

Comment: This answer provides exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094878/4604579

Comment: I want the partial word matching to be contiguous. So, searching for "John Do" should only result in John Doe and not in John X Do which the ngram analyzer is doing.

Comment: No, because that solution uses an ngram tokenizer which tokenizes the whole input and not the separate terms, like an ngram token filter would do

Comment: Is there anything other than ngram that I can use to match my usecase of partial contiguous word matching?

Comment: The example I linked to supports exactly your use case. an Ngram tokenizer will index contiguous words

Comment: I see that example you mentioned in the link for "peter tomson". I do not want the "peter tomson" search result to be returned when I search for "pet son". The characters ALSO need to be contiguos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me.
Instead of an ngram, index your data as keyword.
And use wildcard regex match to match the words.

```
 "query": {
          "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "wildcard": { "Field1": "*" + term + "*" }
                },
                {
                  "wildcard": { "Field2": "*" + term + "*" }
                }
              ],
              "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
      }
```

Comment: Beware, though, that depending on your index size, the performance of your cluster [might suffer big time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html). Ideally, prefix wildcards should be avoided if possible, as it will force ES to do a full index scan. I'm going to provide an alternative solution for those who have a big index and won't be able to use wildcard queries with prefix wildcards.

Answer (score 14):

As explained in my comment above, prefix wildcards should be avoided at all costs as your index grows since that will force ES to do full index scans. I'm still convinced that ngrams (more precisely edge-ngrams) is the way to go, so I'm taking a stab at it below.

The idea is to index all the suffixes of the input and then use a [`prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) to match any suffix as searching for prefixes doesn't suffer the same performance issues as searching for suffixes. So the idea is to index `john doe` as follows:

```
john doe
ohn doe
hn doe
n doe
doe
oe
e
```

That way, using a `prefix` query we can match any sub-part of those tokens which effectively achieves the goal of matching partial contiguous words while at the same time ensuring good performance.

The definition of the index would go like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "reverse",
              "suffixes",
              "reverse"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "suffixes": {
            "type": "edgeNGram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can index a sample document:

```
PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "name": "john doe"
}
```

And finally all of the following searches will return the `john doe` document:

```
POST my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "john doe"
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "john do"
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "ohn do"
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "john"
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": "n doe"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a updated fix

[link to the code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

[more options with tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html)

create index with

```
 body = {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```