# How to search part of a sentece in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch js to make a search engine, like so:

```
  let jobs = await client.search({
      index: 'index',
      type: 'doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match: {
                  title: 'test'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

if the title has 'test' in it , it will show, but when it has something like 'hello this is/test' it wont show up, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the string with `*`:

```
let jobs = await client.search({
  index: 'index',
  type: 'doc',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            match: {
              title: '*test*'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please try prefixing with `.` so `*` is now `.*`. And please also note that if 'test' appears with any uppercase letter it won't find it

Comment: The match query doesn't support wildcard, you need to use the `wildcard` query, but using prefix wildcards is not performant at all

Comment: @Val so how am I suppose to search ?

Comment: Try wildcard, but that's just for testing purposes, depending on the amount of data you have

Comment: @Val wildcard works, but inst there any other way? just to make sure the string is a substring of the field?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478023/query-in-elasticsearch-to-match-part-of-the-word/50596565#50596565

Comment: @Val I can't understand that solution, I'm pretty new to Elasticsearch and I want it in node js not as a query :X could you please simplify the answer? and I dont need variations of searches, I need the exact string, for instance test should be found only if there is test in the string, not tet or tes... so my case is simpler